# How to set empty value to DateField in django model?

Tags: python, django

What am I doing wrong here? I need to set empty value to doing_field.

```
def delete_todo_today(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.POST and request.user.is_authenticated:
        thingtodo = ThingToDo.objects.filter(author = request.user, thing = request.POST.get('item'))
        thingtodo.doing_date = None
        thingtodo.save()
        data = {'message': "%s 's doing_date deleted" % request.POST.get('item')}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Comment: can you please provide the definition of `ThingToDo.doing_date` field ?

Comment: doing_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `.filter()` to get the objects for `thingtodo`. This will return a QuerySet or simply said a list of objects. You can not set an attribute on multiple objects directly.

If you wat to retrieve one object only, use `get()` instead of `.filter()`. This will raise an exception when there it more or less than one object matching.

If you want to update multiple objects, use the `update()` method of the QuerySet:

```
thingtodo.update(doing_date=None)
```

Also make use that you model allows `Null` for the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

by default `models.DateField.empty_strings_allowed` is set to `False`,
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#DateField

try defining `ThingToDo.doing_date` with `options['blank'] = True` something like `doing_date = models.DateField(**options)`